# AWK/GAWK adding character after pattern is matched

Tags: awk, text-formatting, gawk

I have the following data structure in my test file:

```
"111","222","AAABBB","333","444","555"
```

I want to transform the third field so there is a '-' after the 3rd [A-Z] like so:

```
"111","222","AAA-BBB","333","444","555"
```

Is using the split() function the best tool for this job?
Here is what I've attempted:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {split($3, a, "[A-Z]{3}", seps); print seps[1]"/"seps[2]};' test
```

The above command does what I want, but how can I print the whole row including my updated $3 field?
Result:

```
AAA-BBB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="," }{ sub(/[A-Z]{3}/, "&-", $3) }1' file
```

- `[A-Z]{3}` - regex pattern to match 3 uppercase letters
- `&` - stands for the precise substring that was matched by the regexp pattern

---

The output:

```
"111","222","AAA-BBB","333","444","555"
```

Comment: If you cannot use `{3}`, you can always to it longhand with `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]`.

Answer (score 3):

In `awk`, when you reassign the value of a field variable, the value of `$0` is recalculated:

```
$ echo "A B C" | awk '{ $2 = "two"; print $0 }'
A two C
```

So in your case:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {split($3, a, "[A-Z]{3}", seps); $3 = seps[1]"-"seps[2]; print $0}' test
```

Answer (score 3):

Your description of the desired logic isn't 100% clear, but the following Sed command works on your example input:

```
sed 's/[A-Z]/&-/3' test-file.txt
```